# Laravel Auth Problem for Web and Api Routes

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, authentication, oauth

Unfortunately, I can't find a solution for a user case, which must actually occur frequently.

To describe it best, I put here the structure of my routes (web and api) of my laravelapp:

**routes/web.php**

```
get(start|products|product/{id}|contact|inprint|login|register)

get(checkout|checkout/(any))->middleware( auth ) // Checkout is a VUE App
```

**routes/api.php**

```
// only the Vue App use the api
get(user|user_orders|user_address) ->middleware( auth )
post (purchase_order) -> middleware(auth)
```

As you can probably see I want to protect parts of the website. Furthermore, I would like to check every query whether the user is logged in in order to display the logout button in the navbar.

1. Is this even possible with an auth system?
2. is it possible to secure webroutes with a token based (JWT) auth system? I always thought no.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the reverse. That will give you the flexibility to check your auth in your controller with

```
Auth::check();
```

With these simple steps, you can check auth in API routes also. So you can integrate the JWT this also along with auth web routes.

You just need to add

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

In your 'API' middleware group

```
'api' => [
  \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
  \\ existing code...
],
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your solution dont work for me. I build in and logged in over webroute (i used the scaffold login laravel/breeze). after that i can identify the user auth status with auth::check() in the web route but not in the api route. i forgot something?

Comment: I have tried a bit and it works that web and api are protected by auth. 

in web route: ->middelware('auth')
in api route: ->middelware('auth:api')

With this solution, however, the response is not nice or wrong. 
Laravel tries to redirect the user to login as soon as the user is not logged in. no matter if xhr request or normal web request. It would be desirable if the xhr requests returned a 404 with json ['status'=>'Unauthenticated']. You have an solution for this ?