# Laravel 8 - Cant use Api and Web Route at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, routes

I have in my Laravel 8 application and as Auth System I use Laravel Breeze. I have defined several web routes and api routes. Some of them protect via Auth .

```
web route: (get|post::middleware(['auth'])->..)
api route: (get|post::middleware(['auth:api'])->..)
```

in the **kernel.php** i have added in the middlewareGroups -> api array:

```
        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,            
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

In the **config/auth.php** I have set the api driver to session under Guards. By default it is set to token here.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Unfortunately, it does not work with the api routes. I keep getting **{"message": "Unauthenticated."}**. Even if the user is logged in.

Can someone tell me what is not working here?

Comment: why do you have those 2 different guards if they are using the same driver and provider? also to use the `session` driver you need sessions which is provided by the 'web' middleware group which is not applied to the routes in `api.php`

Comment: good comment! That's a fair question! Maybe I still have to adapt it. it's still in development.

Comment: majority of the time the 'api' side would be stateless, which is why by default that uses the 'token' driver ... so it depends what your intentions are with how you want to handle authentication and state

Comment: That is all right! Maybe it helps to see what i want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65889210/laravel-auth-problem-for-web-and-api-routes

Comment: i would stop making these changes and reset everything back to the default ... this isn't an issue with the server side, this is an issue with how the front end works, assuming you are using some javascript front end to make these requests

Comment: @lagbox Thank you for your quick answer. But I can't imagine that there is no solution for such a case. It's not an isolated case, for example, that Vue JS apps are installed in certain places on a website. and if the frontend app wants to check whether the user is allowed to do this at all, there must be a solution here.

Otherwise, this would mean either building an SPA or a pure server-side web application.

Comment: yea its called using tokens to pass for authorization ... that is why the api by default uses tokens ... that is why people use JWT with their front end applications, they aren't doing it just because they have nothing better to do :)  ... but maybe you are looking for 'sanctum' https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: @lagbox Thanks lagbox for your patience. yes I know that. I have built pure serverside and pure client-side applications (SPA) with Auth in the past. 
But now I want to have a mix of both. And I'm starting to realise that a) it's not trivial and b) it's not common. so I'm missing something. 

One question: can I secure the webroutes token based?

Comment: you can pass multiple guards to `auth` ... `auth:web,api`  the first guard that returns the user is now the default for the rest of the request

Comment: @lagbox Yes, I though that sanctum is the solution for my problem. but in the laravel documentation says 
"Laravel Sanctum provides a featherweight authentication system for SPAs (single page applications), mobile applications, and simple, token based APIs. Sanctum allows each user of your application to generate multiple API tokens for their account. These tokens may be granted abilities / scopes which specify which actions the tokens are allowed to perform."